# Disable selection on table

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm in the midst of implementing drag/drop functionality on a table.

**How it works:** User left-clicks on a row; the row gets dimmed and a span is added to the DOM. The span acts as a place-holder for the row and follows the cursor as long as the user holds down the left mouse-button.

**The headache:** When holding down the left mouse-button while moving the mouse; text and images in the table gets highlighted (selected).

Is there any way to disable selection on elements, other than the CSS 3 `user-highlight` property?

Comment: have you looked at jquery ui's draggable and droppable,  (or sortable if your using the drag and drop to sort).  it solves this problem, and many others you may or may not come across by re-inventing this wheel.

Comment: Yes, I have. But I would have to hack my way through if I wanted to implement the functionality I have in mind. Good suggestion thou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden deep inside of the very core of jQuery UI - *jquery.ui.core.js* - adventurous developers will find two undocumented functions for disabling and enabling selection on elements.

Ladies and gentlemen! I give to you! `disableSelection()` and `enableSelection()`.

Answer (score 0):

doing a quick google search finds a bunch of different ways of disableing select.  this one looks pretty nice:
http://solidlystated.com/scripting/proper-way-to-disable-text-selection-and-highlighting/